# unity android build not fitting on screen properly

Tags: unity-game-engine

I made a game in unity 2020.1.0 and when I test it on my phone using Unity Remote 5 it works perfectly.
however when I build it it doesnt fit properly on my screen.

[this is how it looks on my phone](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jd01t.png)

note the red text at the top and the little button bottom left

[this is how its supposed to look](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N8v8a.png)

help?

[this is my canvas](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vyqPG.png)

Isn't this supposed to scale with screen size?

maybe something here?

[player settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PMTi8.png)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Try to scale with height instead of width and see if it works then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For each of your UI object you need to set anchor.
For example
"Reset" button should have top-right anchor set. [IMAGE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eDQ69.png)

Answer (score 0):

I suggest managing the canvas like this

[image]